# How to debug a single Nightwatch JS test in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, selenium, debugging, visual-studio-code, nightwatch.js

I am QA Engineer with very minimal developer experience. My skills are limited to writing automated tests and in my time I have always used Visual Studio Enterprise (with selenium webdriver) and TestComplete IDE's with their in built debugger. I have recently made a move to something new and want to get to grips with Nightwatch JS for my end to end tests. I have written some tests and they are running fine. However, I am now at a stage where a test is failing and I want to debug just that one test. How I would do this??? Usually in VS enterprise or TestComplete, I would just pop a break point on a line of code, right click on the one test script and it will pause at the break point.

For my Nightwatch JS project I have used Visual Studio Code. I know that I can run a single test by opening the terminal in VS Code and running the command "nightwatch tests/folder/path/myTest.js". There is not much help on nightwatch out there that has helped me and the only post I found on here was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43784391/how-to-debug-nightwatch-tests-in-vs-code) one but it has not solved my problem. Because when I click the debugger "Play" button it starts to run ALL of my test not the one test I am interested in.

I have tried to play the debugger and then in the terminal run my cmd for the one test but the test will run through and does not hit my break points. Any guru's out there that can help?

Please ask away if you need me to post any information.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass [additional options](http://nightwatchjs.org/guide/#command-line-options) for Nightwatch in your terminal, such as `--  --tag`.

So, you can tag each single test file you have, like this:

```
module.exports = {
 '@tags': ['iamatag'],
 '[EXAMPLE TEST]': (client) => {
    code
    code
    code
  }
};
```

Then, in your terminal, you would run:

```
$ npm test -- --tag iamatag
```

Only tests with the tag 'iamatag' will run.

Cheers.